# If condition with 2 different values within certain range (boundary)

Tags: bash

Let's say I have a coordinate (x,y), I want to make two categories: good or bad.

I have no idea how to put it into words or keywords, so I created an example of what I want.

I have created a bash script like this:

```
x=3.5 #(example)
y=-2.5 #(example)
if [ $x -ge 0.1 -a $x -le 5.5 ] && [ $y -ge -5.9 -a $y -le -0.1 ]; then cat="good";
elif [ $x -ge 5.5 -a $x -le 10.5 ] && [ $y -ge -10.9 -a $y -le -5.9 ]; then cat="bad";
fi
echo "$cat"
```

On that script I want to know if x is within range 0.1 till 5.5 (0.1 < x < 5.5) and y within -5.9 till -0.1 (-5.9 < y < -0.1) are true then it gives result as `good`. With different boundaries it should give a `bad` result.

I've run it and it gives the result as integer expression expected.

When I try to replace the operator `-ge` (or `-le`) with operator `>` (or `<`), or try to add a square bracket and anything I could think of, it gives the same error or no results are given.

How should I approach this?

Comment: just use `else` for your 2nd condition, and `<` or `>` aren't use to compare number but character place in ASCII table

Comment: That's because bash can only do integer math. Do the values have at most one decimal place? Then you can simply multiply all of them by 10 and you have integers. If they are arbitrary precision, you could use `bc`.

Comment: because what will be the result if `x=3.5` and `y=-7.9` ?

Comment: there will be another 'elif' for certain boundary, i just put two to make it an example

Comment: if im gonna use bc, where should i put it?

Comment: Please tell us where you get the values from and which format they have.

Comment: the value actually not given like that, its from reading txt files on certain keywords using awk. i've echoed the value to test if its give right result and nothing is the problem till this step.

Comment: If you're already processing your data in `awk`, it would probably make more sense to let `awk` do the arithmetic

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bash can only do integer math. If the values have a fixed number of decimal places, you can remove the `.` (using `sed` or `awk` or any command you like) and compare the resulting values. For example, if they have exactly one decimal place like `10.0, 0.4, 2.2`, removing the `.` will multiply them by ten, resulting in `100, 04, 22` (using the old test command `[`, leading `0`s don't matter for integer comparison). You'll have to multiply the boundaries accordingly, of course.

Alternatively, you can use `bc`, which will work with arbitrary precision floating point numbers. `bc` reads `stdin`, so you can, for example, echo the expression and pipe it to `bc` as follows:

```
echo "$x>=0.1 && $x<=5.5" | bc
```

The output will be `1` if the expression is `true`, `0` otherwise. Read the manual ([man bc](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/bc.1.html)) if you want to learn more about its syntax.

To incorporate this in your script, you can use command substitution like this:

```
if [ $(echo "$x>=0.1 && $x<=5.5" | bc) -eq 1 ] ; then cat="good";
```

Note that we still need to check if the `bc` command's output is `1`, because `[ 0 ]` will also evaluate to `true`.

Finally, your example using `bc`:

```
x=6.5 #(example)
y=-7.5 #(example)
if [ $(echo "$x>=0.1 && $x<=5.5 && $y>=-5.9 && $y<=-0.1" | bc) -eq 1 ] ; then cat="good";
elif [ $(echo "$x>=5.5 && $x<=10.5 && $y>=-10.9 && $y<=-5.9" | bc) -eq 1 ]; then cat="bad";
fi
echo "$cat"
```

---

Since having those hardly readable strings inside the brackets makes it more error prone, you can use bash functions and variables like in the following example. This may be useful if you want to add additional `elif` clauses with different ranges. (Thanks to [wjandrea](https://askubuntu.com/users/301745/wjandrea) for the useful hints)

```
x=6.5 #(example)
y=-6.5 #(example)

boundsGood="0.1 5.5 -5.9 -0.1"
boundsBad="5.5 10.5 -10.9 -5.9"

# Paramaters in following order: x, y, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax; bounds are inclusive.
function in_bounds {
    local x=$1
    local y=$2
    local x_min=$3
    local x_max=$4
    local y_min=$5
    local y_max=$6
    [ $(echo "$x >= $x_min && $x <= $x_max && $y >= $y_min && $y <= $y_max" | bc) -eq 1 ]
}

if in_bounds $x $y $boundsGood ; then cat="good";
elif in_bounds $x $y $boundsBad ; then cat="bad";
fi
echo "$cat"
```

Alternative version of the `in_bounds` function using `printf` (thanks to [steeldriver](https://askubuntu.com/users/178692/steeldriver)):

```
# Paramaters in following order: x, y, xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax; bounds are inclusive.
function in_bounds {
    [ $(printf "x = %f; y = %f; xmin = %f; xmax = %f; ymin = %f; ymax = %f; x >= xmin && x <= xmax && y >= ymin && y <= ymax\n" "$1" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5" "$6" | bc) -eq 1 ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If it's absolutely necessary to remain within shell script - prepend variables to `awk` embedded script to pass the `x` and `y` values into awk's environment and use `ENVIRON["variable_name"]` to access them; and let it do the job of printing the strings you need (or wrap the whole script into `$(...)` to save the output).

If it's not necessary, do away with shell script part, and just let awk alone handle everything.

```bsh
#!/bin/sh

x=3.5
y=-2.5
x="$x" y="$y" awk 'BEGIN{ 
        print ENVIRON["x"],ENVIRON["y"];
        if ((ENVIRON["x"] >= 0.1) && (ENVIRON["x"] <= 5.5) \
           && (ENVIRON["y"] >= -5.9) &&  (ENVIRON["y"] <= -0.1)){
              print "good";
        }
        else if ((ENVIRON["x"] >= 5.5) && (ENVIRON["x"] <= 10.5) \
           && (ENVIRON["y"] >= -10.9) &&  (ENVIRON["y"] <= -5.9)){
             print "bad";
        }

}' # End of awk
```